# Python: str.split() removes trailing number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please explain to me this behaviour in Python 3.7 and Ipython ?

```
'asdf1 001.csv'.strip('001.csv')
Out[6]: 'asdf1 '
'asdf1 001.csv'.strip(' 001.csv')
Out[7]: 'asdf'
```

Focus on the last numer (`1`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows the logic that is outlined in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

and also:

> The outermost leading and trailing chars argument values are stripped from the string. Characters are removed from the leading end until reaching a string character that is not contained in the set of characters in chars.

It also provides an example which helps understand the behaviour:

```
'www.example.com'.strip('cmowz.')
>'example'
```

Answer (score 1):

As from documentation provided lower - strip removes from start and end in any order all the chars provided in brackets until reaches other char. In first case no space so it stops removing at space, in second case it removes space and following 1 as it is also is present in a set.

docs from here:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip

```
str.strip([chars])
Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

>>>
>>> '   spacious   '.strip()
'spacious'
>>> 'www.example.com'.strip('cmowz.')
'example'
The outermost leading and trailing chars argument values are stripped from the string. Characters are removed from the leading end until reaching a string character that is not contained in the set of characters in chars. A similar action takes place on the trailing end. For example:

>>>
>>> comment_string = '#....... Section 3.2.1 Issue #32 .......'
>>> comment_string.strip('.#! ')
'Section 3.2.1 Issue #32'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythons `str.rstrip` doesn't remove the string `' 001.csv'`, it removes every char which is contained in `' 001.csv'` from the end until the string ends with another character. So, in your first example `'001.csv'` doesn't contain a space and the function is done with `'asdf1 '`. In your second example, `rstrip` doesn't stop after removing the space because `' 001.csv'` still contains a `'1'`